# How can I write an efficient php chat?

Tags: php, chat, bandwidth

I wrote a PHP chatscript with JQUERY on the userend pullstyle. It reloaded a pull.php page once a second and retrieved only new chat records from my sql database since the last check.

However I got an email from my host saying I was using too much bandwidth. Bleh. My chat was working just as I wanted it and this happened. I'm scared to do a COMET php chat because I was told it uses a separate process or thread foreach user.

I suppose I just need a strategy that's good, and more efficient than what I had.

Comment: very difficult for us to help without seeing code or information such as amount of data being transfered back and fort during chat. Also remember to accept answers peoples give you it will motivate others to help you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you've got the premise down.  1 second recalls are far too frequent - can anyone bang out a response in a second and expect it to go through?  It takes me at least 2 seconds to get my SO messages together / relatively typo free.

So part 1 - increase the recall time.  You kick it up to 10 seconds, the app is still going to feel pretty speedy, but you're decreasing processing by a factor of 10 - that's huge.  Remember every message includes extra data (in the HTML and in all the network layers that support it), and every received message by the server requires processing to decide what to do with it.

Part 2 - You might want to introduce a sliding scale of interactivity speed. When the user isn't typing and hasn't received a message in a while the recheck rate could be decreased to perhaps 30 seconds.  If the user is receiving more than one message in a "pull" or has received a message for the last 3 consecutive pulls then the speed should increase (perhaps even more frequent than 10 seconds).  This will feel speedy to users during conversations, and not slow/laggy when there's nothing going on.

Part 3 - Sounds like you're already doing it, but your pull should be providing the minimum possible reply.  That is just the HTML fragment to render the new messages, or perhaps even just a JSON structure that can be rendered by client-side JavaScript.  If you're getting all the messages again (bad) or the whole page again (worse) you can seriously decrease your bandwidth this way.

Part 4 - You may want to look at alternate server software.  Apache has some serious overhead... and that's for good reason, you've got all your plugs running, apache config, .htaccess config, rewrites, the kitchen sink - you might be able to switch to a lighter weight http server - nginx, lighttp - and realise some serious performance increase (strictly speaking it won't help much with bandwidth - but one wonders if that's what the host is really complaining about, or that your service consumes serious server resources).

Part 5 - You could look at switching host, or package - a horrible thought I'm sure, but there may be packages with more bandwidth/processor (the later being more key I suspect) available... you could even move to your own server which allows you to do what you want without the service provider getting involved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for a new message every second, kick it down to maybe 3 or 4. Make sure you are only using 1 query and that the file loaded is as small as possible. And I would always add a timeout... it would stop reloading after a minute or 2 of no activity.

Make these changes and see where that puts you.

Post some code if you want to see if we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that comet is the only solution.

Threads are much lighter than processes, so you would want to use a COMET type technology with a light threaded web server like lighthttpd.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Simple Chat](http://arkanis.de/projects/simple-chat/). It's very tiny and extensible i think.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is "move ahead with one of the standard solutions available"....

Comet, Web Socket, XMPP are a few words you will hear every now n then, just pick one of them and it should be more efficient than classic periodic ajax call based php chat.

If you want to go ahead with PHP and jQuery based solution, try these two working examples of browser based chat system using XMPP: http://bit.ly/jaxlBoshChat (for one-to-one chat example) and http://bit.ly/jaxlBoshMUC (for multi-user chat example). Let me know if you face any problem setting them up.